# Counting visitors in a node http server

Tags: node.js, http, count

My source code:

```
 var http = require("http");
 var count=1;

 http.createServer(function(request, response) {
 response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});    
 response.write("Hi, you are number "+count+" visitors");
 response.end();
 count++;
  }).listen(8888);
```

I got 1,3,5,7,..... in each visit. Why to increment the count by 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The request to `favicon.ico` is triggering an extra request (I confirmed this by logging the details for each request and then making a normal request with Chrome).

You will need to look explicitly for the type of request (url, method, etc) you're wanting to match.

Also, keep in mind, if your server dies, which it probably will at some stage, your count will be reset. If you don't want that, you should persist it somewhere less volatile, such as a database.

Comment: The type of request? I simply use localhost:8888 in a browser. When I reset the server, it starts from 1,3,5,... all over again.

Comment: @user1780176 I mean examine the request's information, such as the URL. I didn't mean the type as in `GET`,`POST`, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that the event is triggered and then the command is executed. The event loop only runs once. Right?

Comment: @user1780176 I think you're misunderstanding something. Just log the `request` object (`console.log(request)`) and you will see for yourself.

Comment: OK, I see lots of stuff. You are saying the event loop is triggered twice in this case?

Comment: @user1780176 I don't know if *event loop* is the correct terminology. But two requests come in, so the callback is triggered twice.

Comment: Two requests come in in one visit? I have to think about it. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @user1780176 Indeed. If you're not sure what a favicon is, research and you'll see why two requests are made. Incidentally, if serve up a `/favicon.ico`, you won't get the double request behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is just a simple counter and knowing that the request to `favicon.ico` is triggering an extra request, then you can simple count every request as a half so it will result in exact number of visits.

```
counter = counter + 0.5;
```

Comment: That's pretty fragile, you can't guarantee that every request is going to attempt to grab `favicon.ico` too.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore the request for the favicon.ico:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/favicon.ico'){
        console.log('favicon');
        return;
    }
    userCount++;
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('Hello!\n');
    res.write('We have had ' + userCount + ' visits!\n');
    res.end();

});
```